# Basics of inertia in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to produce a draggable element with inertia when you move it. I am pretty new to JavaScript, looking for the basics of doing it. I would like to use a library like jquery ui for the drag n drop functionality then add inertia, I have done some as3 inertia but am wondering where to begin with JavaScript.

Comment: A little bit of vector math would go a long way in this case. Marking the click and release, then continuing that path would be the basic concept.